# Is Highmaps supported for iOS in Highcharts framework?

Tags: ios, highcharts, geojson

I wanna load data using HIMapDataObject for my iOS app, 
I have a GeoJSON file data that I want to load with Highmaps using Highcharts framework.
how is that possible ?

Comment: Please be more informative by adding the info regarding what have you tried to counter the problem.

Comment: I'm actually using Highcharts framework, and I want to use the map provided by this framework to load my data (GeoJson data) , but there is no documentation ?  this is the guithub  link of the simple project that I'm using https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-ios , and I want to get this result https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/geojson using with iOS

Comment: I meant to post the same thing in the question which you have just posted in the comments.

Comment: Unfortunately, Highstock and Highmaps are not supported on iOS.